# Text File to Vector In C++

Tags: c++, vector, text-files

I'm having trouble getting elements of a text file into a vector for CS homework. I'm getting stuck on what to put as the condition for the while loop I'm using to fill the vector.

```
while(inFile >> ?)
{
  vector.push_back();
}
```

I've tried the name of the vector as the condition and looked up this same question on Google, but all I get is formatting like (std : : ). I haven't learned that yet, so I can't use it.

Please help!

Comment: Please post the whole code so that we can reproduce the issue. What type of vector are you using? what is inFile?

Comment: `std::string word; while (file >> word) { vector.push_back(word); }` If you want to read whole lines instead use `while (std::getline(...) { ... }`. You can find plenty of examples of both here if you search.

Comment: I highly don't recommend doing that with std::vector, without first doing a vector.reserve, or vector.resize.  -- As your vector will continually be required to resize itself.